# "LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session" - in fact, no session to be found anywhere

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to debug pre-existing code making use of Hibernate and JPA. The error message makes sense, and even has several other questions on SO discussing it. But when I look for a session to keep open, I find that "session" is mentioned nowhere in the entire code body (aside from HTTP sessions - a completely different thing). Moreover, the code looks like it ought to work, which leads me to believe there is state information I can't see, but I cannot figure out what type of state I should try to look for.

I'll try to post a simple example, although I can't verify the following will do the same thing, due to all the dependencies involved. Hopefully it will suffice to say that the exception appears to be 100% reliably thrown, leading me to believe I'm merely overlooking something reasonably trivial.

The code acquires an instance of a class defined as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "some_object")
public class SomeObject {
    @Valid
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "other_object_id")
    private OtherObject otherObject;
    // ...lots of other declarations
    public OtherObject getOtherObject() {return this.otherObject;}
    // ...lots of other accessors
}
```

From this instance, another object is acquired, and an attribute is called on it in turn:

```
OtherObject other = someObject.getOtherObject();
String strVal = otherObject.getOtherString();
```

where OtherObject is declared as (partially) follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "other_object")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class OtherObject {
    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "other_string")
    private String otherString;
    // ...
    public String getOtherString() { return this.otherString; }
    // ...
}
```

The `LazyInitializationException` occurs on the retrieval of the string from `otherObject`.

Why don't I get the `LIE` on the acquisition of `someObject` (it's acquired via some JPA code that I *think* is irrelevant here)?

I thought I could assume that since the first accessor probably results in a database query, which returns successfully, that the second one ought to as well. Is this incorrect?

Perhaps `otherObject` is "already here", and causes no query, whereas retrieving `otherString` is not. How can I test this? There is no code dealing with `Session` instances anywhere, and any calls to `detach` objects seem to occur in completely inapplicable locations. Should I look harder? Should I pursue the rabbit hole that getting Hibernate SQL logging to work in Tomcat appears to be?

Or is there no way to tell on what I've given here? Should I add more detail?

Answer (score 2):

Since `otherObject` is fetched lazily, when you execute `getOtherObject()` there is no database query. The lazy proxy object is returned. When you want to examine its *contents*, i.e. `otherObject.otherString` database access happens.

If you're not working in a transactional context (i.e. a session isn't open), you get `LazyInitializationException`. You can fix this by either fetching `otherObject` eagerly (how this is done depends on how you load the initial `SomeObject`) or by having a transaction/session open so the query can be executed lazily.

It's also not very hard to log SQL queries done by Hibernate.

Comment: Nice answer, and probably the best I can get given how little info I was able to give. The point about the lazy proxy also makes total sense, although now I wonder: `someObject` was acquired from generated Hibernate service code (I think), and now I'm wondering why it didn't throw an exception, either. I'm comfortable admitting I don't understand this code well enough yet, so the question is figuring out what it's doing.